# Is it possible to have ExUnit.test statement inside a Enum.each

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to do something like this to not have to write manually a series of `test` blocks:

```
test_cases = %{
  "foo" => 1,
  "bar" => 2,
  "baz" => 3,
}

Enum.each(test_cases, fn({input, expected_output}) ->
  test "for #{input}" do
    assert(Mymodule.myfunction input) == expected_output
  end
end)
```

But when running this code I get the error `undefined function input/0` on the line `assert(Mymodule.myfunction input) == expected_output`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just have to `unquote` both `input` and `expected_output` inside the `do` block that you pass to `test/2`.

```
test_cases = %{
  "foo" => 1,
  "bar" => 2,
  "baz" => 3,
}

Enum.each test_cases, fn({input, expected_output}) ->
  test "for #{input}" do
    assert Mymodule.myfunction(unquote(input)) == unquote(expected_output)
  end
end
```

Btw, you had a parens error in the `assert` line as you were calling `assert/1` with just `Mymodule.myfunction input` as its argument, instead of `Mymodule.myfunction(input) == expected_output` (which is the expression you're trying to assert on).